# Follow user and tags system

Tags: mysql

User can follow by another user or tag.

**My database:**

```
POSTS (id, user_id, name, content)
USERS (id, username)
TAGS (id, name)
TAGS_ASSIGNMENTS (post_id, tag_id)
USERS_FOLLOW (user_id, follow_user_id)
TAGS_FOLLOW (user_id, follow_tag_id)
```

I need one request to get all the post, where I follow users and tags...
Can someone hale me with that?

I can create on request for users and one for tags, but not together

Comment: Check out the `JOIN`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use both JOIN and UNION in this case, Try below:

```
select a.name, a.content from POSTS a where user_id in (
    select follow_user_id from USERS_FOLLOW where user_id = @userid)
UNION DISTINCT
select a.name, a.content from POSTS a where id in (
    select post_id from TAGS_ASSIGNMENTS a, TAGS_FOLLOW b where 
        a.tag_id = b.follow_tag_id and b.user_id = @userid)
```

Here @userid is the input User Id